# Zero-Knowledge proof of inequality

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I think it's neat how a person can prove that [two discrete logarithms are equal without actually revealing the value](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/voting/papers/CramerDamgardSchoenmakers-ProofsOfPartialKnowledge.pdf).

So, conversely, is there a way for me to prove that two discrete logarithms are not equal without revealing either logarithm's value?  Assume that I know (by construction or by oracle) the discrete logarithm value for any pair of elements (from the 4 given elements) and I thereby know that all are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A zero-knowledge algorithm for proving inequality of two discrete logarithms was given e.g. by Camenisch and Shoup in Section 6 of [Practical Verifiable Encryption and Decryption of Discrete Logarithms](http://www.shoup.net/papers/verenc.pdf) (CRYPTO'03).

Quoting  from the paper:

> Let $G=\langle g \rangle$ be a group of prime order $q$. The prover
>   and verifier have common inputs $g, h, y, z \in G$ where $g, h$ are
>   generators of $G$ and $log_g y \neq log_h z$. The prover has the
>   additional input $x = log_g y$. The prover and the verifier then
>   engage in the following protocol.
>
> 1. The prover randomly chooses $r \in Z_q$, computes the auxiliary commitment $C = (h ^x/z)^r$, and sends $C$ to the verifier.
> 2. The prover executes the protocol denoted $PK\left\{(\alpha, \beta) : C = h^\alpha (\frac{1}{z})^\beta \wedge 1 = g^\alpha (\frac{1}{y})^\beta \right\}$ with the verifier. (Note that this is a
>      proof of equality, so we know how to do this).
> 3. The verifier accepts if it accepts in Step 2, and if $C \neq 1$; otherwise, the verifier rejects.
>
> This constitutes an honest-verifier proof system for proving that
>   $log_g y \neq hog_h z$.

Comment: BTW. In the LNCS version of this paper, it's Section 5.

Comment: If you have a simple procedure for step #2, please spell it out, so that I can compare the complexity with other answers.

Comment: Step 2 is for instance spelled out as Protocol 1 in Henry and Goldberg, Thinking inside the BLAC box: smarter protocols for faster anonymous blacklisting. WPES 2013: 71-82. https://www.cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/blacronym-wpes.pdf https://dblp.org/rec/conf/wpes/HenryG13.html

Answer (score 2):

It could be a proof of knowledge of some $z$ such that $z (x - y) = 1$. The idea is, such an inverse only exists for non equal $x$ and $y$ committed. It works for groups of a prime and hidden (unknown to Prover) order.

Comment: Do you have a reference or the actual steps needed here so I can compare the complexity with other answers?

Comment: This would be a self-reference. Existence of an inverse (in context of polynomial graph representation) could be found at "Zero-Knowledge Proofs via Polynomial Representations", LNCS 7464. A product of vertex color differences was proved there to be non-zero. A Schnorr-like protocol was suggested with "powers in the challenge". Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This elaborates on Krystian's answer, but looks different since I then
simplified the process.  Given: $g,h,y,z$ where only the prover knows the secret $x$ such that $y=g^x$

Prover chooses random secret $a,b,c$ and reveals:

$$\begin{align}
t_1 &= z^a\\
t_2 &= y^a\\
t_3 &= h^{xa}\\
t_4 &= z^b\\
t_5 &= y^b\\
t_6 &= h^c\\
t_7 &= g^c\\
\end{align}$$

Verifier chooses and reveals random $k$.
Prover reveals:

$$\begin{align}
t_8 &= b+ak\\
t_9 &= c+xak
\end{align}$$

Verifier confirms:

$$\begin{align}   
z^{t_8} &= t_4t_1^k\\
y^{t_8} &= t_5t_2^k\\
h^{t_9} &= t_6t_3^k\\
g^{t_9} &= t_7t_2^k\\
t_1 &\neq t_3
\end{align}$$

(If the last confirmation found equality instead, we have a long-winded
zero-knowledge proof for equality of logarithms.)

I'm still hoping someone might answer with a simpler process.  By the way,
is there a process which transfers even less knowldege by appearing the
same when either logarithm is known (i.e., when the prover instead knew
$x_2$ such that $z=h^{x_2}$)?  With the process here, the verifier learns that the base-g logarithm is known.